# Using Selenium to test Safari gives GridException

Tags: selenium, grid

I am using the code from this site (http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-selenium-20-with-webdriver-and.html) to run Selenium tests in Safari 5. The code goes like this:

```
Selenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*safari", baseURL);
CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(sel);
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
WebDriver browser = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, dc);

browser.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement input = browser.findElement(By.name("q"));
input.sendKeys("Selenium");
```

So I start a Selenium server standalone version on the localhost machine and I register a test node (also on localhost) to the Selenium hub. Then I start the test. I then get the following exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Could not start Selenium session: org%2Eopenqa%2Egrid%2Ecommon%2Eexception%2EGridException%3A+Error+forwarding+the+new+session+The+server+returned+an+error+%3A+

I don't know what error. There is no server output on the console. Does anyone have ideas? I used the newest version (2.17.0) of Selenium.

EDIT: I just tried "firefox" instead of safari and it outputs the same exception. So actually it's not the fault of safari. Maybe there is something wrong with executing Selenium 1 code via the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
capabilities.setBrowserName("safari");
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(new URL("http://localhost:5555/"), new URL("http://www.google.com/"), capabilities); 
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, capabilities); 
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Don't create DefaultSelenium object. The above code works well for me with Safari browser.

Comment: this gives me the following exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Could not start Selenium session: org%2Eopenqa%2Egrid%2Ecommon%2Eexception%2EGridException%3A+Error+forwarding+the+new+session+cannot+find+%3A+%7BbrowserName%3D%2Asafari%7D

how do you register the test machine to the hub? i used "-browser browserName=safari"

Comment: Don't give browser name when you create Grid node.